# 301 redirect bulk aspx URLs on IIS

Tags: redirects, 301-redirect, drupal, iis7, aspx

We recently relaunched an old ASPX site as a new Drupal site on the same domain. No 301 redirect was implemented.

I have outputted a list of 1000 URLs that need to be 301 redirected. Most of the URLs are the results of search queries that were committed on the website. I.E.:

```
http://www.mysite.com/electronics/CommunityDetails.aspx?FirstLetter=%&ID=444
```

We are running a Drupal site on IIS using a PHP plugin. Is there a way I can wild card a redirect of all ASPX pages? I know I can do it with *.htaccess* but that doesn't apply here. Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/deployment/using-asp-net-mvc-with-different-versions-of-iis-cs to wild card route, I don't know what version of IIS you are using, it's much easier in IIS 7.5. -  I've set up a redirection rule (after I've installed the "URL Rewrite" IIS module).

Here's is the rule:

```
Request URL: Matches the Pattern
Using: Wildcards
Pattern: (.*)
Logical grouping: Match All
Input {HTTP_HOST}
Type: Matches the PAttern
Pattern: www\.mydomainname.com\.com
Action Type: Redirect
Redirect URL: mydomainname.com{R:1}
Redirect Type: 301
```

Comment: Hello, my problem is that all the pages that google has marked as 404's are dynamic queries from a search form. We don't have any server caching as we are on a dynamic ip. Why/how did they get crawled? I am getting penalised by google and have lost 80% of clicks. Is there a way of contacting google and stating that these pages can't be 301'd and shouldn't have been crawled, please remove from the index? Network admin says there is nothing else he can do. I'm totally f'd right now.

Comment: Those pages are marked as 404 in Google? They shouldn't be the reason of your drop in clicks then. If they were indexed, you could've been penalized for duplicate content, but if they show as 404, it's not that. You relaunched the site, what did you change? I would start by looking there.